# What is the significance of God exhorting Joshua to be strong and VERY courageous in Joshua 1:7?

Tags: joshua

Related question: [Why would God have to tell Joshua three different times to “be strong and of good courage”?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/52912/why-would-god-have-to-tell-joshua-three-different-times-to-be-strong-and-of-goo)

In Joshua 1, God exhorts Joshua 3 times:

> 6a Be strong and courageous ...
> 7a Be strong and **very** courageous. ...
> 9b Be strong and courageous. ...

Is there a significance that in the 2nd time, God adds the word "very"?

Comment: When in fear and trepidation, I need considerable persuading to take another step. It does not surprise me that Joshua would need a **lot** of persuading, considering the daunting tasks that lay ahead of him, and considering the past failures of Israel in the wilderness. Up-voted +1.

Answer (score 1):

I would answer in a similar fashion to the way I answered previously.  Of the triple charge that God gave Joshua (Josh 1:5-9) after the death of Moses, the second would be the most challenging; namely,

> V7 Be careful to observe all the law that My servant Moses commanded
> you

leadership is a heavy burden to bear.  BUT leadership can only be achieved, according to this passage with three things:

1. The strength provided by God
2. Adhering to the "rule of law"
3. Great courage and consistency

Sticking to the rule of law, "Be careful to observe all the law that My servant Moses commanded you", is the most tempting to abandon at times - it is where almost all failed states in history have collapsed such as Afghanistan, Burma, etc, etc.

It is all too easy to ignore some regulation to the immediate benefit of either oneself or the situation at hand to the detriment of other things.  This requires great consistency and very great courage and God required.